# How do I access data in a nested json with lists?

Tags: javascript, json

This has been a real pain for me and I can't solve it. I have a Json that looks like this:

```
"name": "The data",
"list": [
    {
        "item": "a613424",
        "locations": [
            {
                "name": "start",
                "a": 5.743,
                "b": 0.093
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item": "e88934",
        "locations": [
            {
                "name": "start",
                "a": 6.64,
                "b": 0.43
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "item": "d92213",
        "locations": [
            {
                "name": "start",
                "a": 12.33,
                "b": 0.91
            },
            {
                "name": "stop",
                "a": 889,
                "b": 1.134
            }
        ]
    }]}
```

Every item has an item code, and in locations has a name and values for a and b. Some items have 2 names. I need to read through this and extract the item code, name(s) and a and b values. I don't know how many items will be in the json or which items will have multiple names.

I either get an object returned or 'unknown'

```
x = test_data.list[0]; document.write(x);
```

outputs [object object]

```
document.write(test_data[0]);
```

outputs 'undefined'

I could do this in 5 minutes in Python, but sadly this has to be in javascript.

Thanks

Comment: `document.write(JSON.stringify(x));`

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do. Please update the question with all the details.

Comment: have you fetched the json file

Comment: as you mentioned in a comment that you need to extract code, name , a,b so in that case if you have two objects then how it will work need to override the value? can you write the raw logic how this JSON will be processed in your scenario

Answer (score 0):

Access the lists through `forEach` and `item` and `locations` properties. It's easy since you have a constant structure for your JSON

```js
let data = {
  "name": "The data",
  "list": [{
      "item": "a613424",
      "locations": [{
        "name": "start",
        "a": 5.743,
        "b": 0.093
      }]
    },
    {
      "item": "e88934",
      "locations": [{
        "name": "start",
        "a": 6.64,
        "b": 0.43
      }]
    },
    {
      "item": "d92213",
      "locations": [{
          "name": "start",
          "a": 12.33,
          "b": 0.91
        },
        {
          "name": "stop",
          "a": 889,
          "b": 1.134
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let listItems = data.list;
listItems.forEach(item => {
  console.log("item code: " + item.item); // item code
  item.locations.forEach(location => {
    console.log("location a is: " + location.a); // a
    console.log("location b is: " + location.b); // b
  });
  console.log("\n"); //for breakline
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let objectData = {
  name: "The data",
  list: [
    {
      item: "a613424",
      locations: [
        {
          name: "start",
          a: 5.743,
          b: 0.093
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      item: "e88934",
      locations: [
        {
          name: "start",
          a: 6.64,
          b: 0.43
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      item: "d92213",
      locations: [
        {
          name: "start",
          a: 12.33,
          b: 0.91
        },
        {
          name: "stop",
          a: 889,
          b: 1.134
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

let obDList = objectData.list.map((x) =>
  x.locations.map((y) => {
    return `a = ${y.a}, b = ${y.b} `;
  })
);

console.log(obDList);
console.log(obDList[2][1]);
```

Comment: Please add more information to your answer so as to make it more comprehensive